# Xcode does not accept provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have created a provisioning profile with e.g. Siri, app groups and imported it into Xcode.
Now Xcode says that:

> provisioning profile "" doesn't support the "" App Group.

My project is a fork (https://github.com/vector-im/element-ios) and it also contains a file config file:

```
// App identity
BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME = Element
BASE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = im.vector.app
APPLICATION_GROUP_IDENTIFIER = group.im.vector
APPLICATION_SCHEME = element

// Team
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 7J4U792NQT


// Provisioning profiles
RIOT_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = Vector App Store
RIOT_PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 4b43c1ca-3246-4984-828f-165838f5715a

NSE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "Vector NSE: App Store"
NSE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE = de44ca91-4318-4c23-8611-b531793505c2

SHARE_EXTENSION_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "Vector Share Extension: App Store"
SHARE_EXTENSION_PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 546090a2-77ca-4bc2-b904-da5bd97a2f37

SIRI_INTENTS_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "Vector Siri Intents: App Store"
SIRI_INTENTS_PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 6951ad31-4850-445a-89c8-b64bca0a1c44
```

Can someone please help me with that? I can not figure out what the specifier of the provisioning profile is and why Xcode does not detect the provisioning profile right.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem. Solved it by folowing this guide to delete the Provisioning Profiles already imported under xCode : https://www.rampfesthudson.com/how-do-i-delete-all-provisioning-profiles-in-xcode/

Then in developer.apple.com I added an App Group (under Identifiers), then edited my App ID to add App Groups as a new Capability, and finally recreated a new Provisioning Profile, and it was good !

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did the same thing you mentioned and it solved my issue. Thanks!